Limit depth of model_dump in pydantic
Pydantic will convert a complex model into a dictionary if you call model_dump. For example:
class Level3(BaseModel):
    deep_field: str


class Level2(BaseModel):
    mid_field: str
    level3: Level3


class Level1(BaseModel):
    top_field: str
    level2: Level2


class DepthLimitedModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    level1: Level1

    max_mapping_depth: ClassVar[int] = 1

new_model = DepthLimitedModel(name="Test", level1=Level1(top_field="Top", level2=Level2(mid_field="Mid", level3=Level3(deep_field="Deep")))
dumped = new_model.model_dump()

The above code would dump the entire structure into a dict. Cool, but we don't want the whole structure. We want to limit the depth of the dump based on our max_mapping_depth variable. In this case, we have set the value to 1 which means we want the dump to include DepthLimitedModel as well as Level1, but the Level2 field on Level1 should just be the object id (and the recursive serialization should end).
I can't find an intuitive way to accomplish this, but, limiting recursion depth seems like it would be so common that a solution must exist.

In your model structure all fields are non-optional. Excluding any of them during serialization will brake the model schema. So, first you need to make levels optional.

Usually I face similar situation when I need to serialize DB model, that has recursion (e.g. Person.parent is Person).
To solve this I create two variants of Person: Person and PersonWithParent.
Person doesn't have parent field, but PersonWithParent has.
This way you limit depth. And the model schema is clear.
